# How to know a week of determinated date in months - ASP MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, week-number

I'm working in ASP using MVC 4, and i try to know the number of week in month. For example, the user inserts `05/02/2014`, and i in controller needs to know the number of week from this date.
For example:
The user insert `04/02/2014` and i gets result `6`

Edit: 
Using format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: How does 04/02/2014 result in 6? If 04/02 represents mm/dd there are five weeks in April. If it represents dd/mm there are still five weeks in February.

Comment: `var cal = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
            cal.GetWeekOfYear(DateTime.Now,System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);` Try that.

Comment: Sorry, i'm using format dd/mm

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893267/304683)

Comment: Ah, now I understand. You're trying to get the number of that week in the year. In other words, you would expect a number between 1 and 52. I misread and thought you wanted to know how many weeks were in the month represented by the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve your problem -

**UPDATED** With string DateTime conversion

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("28/02/2014","dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var cal = System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.Calendar;
cal.GetWeekOfYear(dt, System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, System.DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Comment: Ok, but how i can calc the week of determined date?

Comment: i obtain FormatException in `DateTime dt`

Comment: @CesarMiguel Can you post your date with which you are testing?